# Seeding rand() in C independently of time

Tags: c, random

I am using stdlib to generate random numbers. I know there are better generators but stdlib is quite enough for me.

I am doing:

```
while(condition){
    sleep(1);
    srand(time(NULL));
    r=rand();
}
```

It is inside a loop so I need `sleep(1)` or the seed is the same and the number is repeated. The fact is that I need to generate thousands or maybe millions of numbers and if I wait 1 second per number it will take a long time.
So there is another way independently of time to seed?

Comment: You only need to seed the PRNG once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to seed once (at startup), then generate as many numbers as you like. Don't reseed once per number - it's pointless, and you'd basically have to generate random seeds to generate random numbers (which rather defeats the purpose of using a PRNG in the first place).

Comment: On some systems, you could seed your PRNG (once at startup) from some other random source, e.g. from [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html)